# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass - polymorphic associations and API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Factual API and comments (polymorphic associations). I've also used [**this**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised) tutorial.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_commentable

  ...

def load_commentable
   klass = [Bar, Photo, Event].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"] }
   @commentable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
end
```

Link to new comment:

```
<%= link_to "New Comment", [:new, @commentable, :comment] %>
```

Before this I've had separate model for 'bar comments' and I've saved factual_id with every comment and later list them. How to do that using comment with polymorphic associations?

Comment: Quick patch is to `def nil.name; "John Doe" end`.

Comment: I also use an additional API. Could you explain further for this specific case?